# Blink an image from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel

I want to give some feedback to users when they click on a button, which starts a request that can be long.

I'm using WPF with mvvm and I'd like to start blink the clicked image.

This is the XAML code:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnToolBar}" Command="{Binding refreshAll}">
     <Image x:Name="imgUpd" Style="{DynamicResource ImageStyleUpd}" ToolTip="{StaticResource UpdateData}"/>
</Button>
```

I'd like something like:

```
isBlinking="{Binding isBlinking}"
```

Does it exist? How can I make a blinking image from the ViewModel? Is it possible?

EDIT: I have written this with the [solution](https://programmingistheway.wordpress.com/2015/06/24/mvvm-and-wpf-blink-an-image-from-view-model/) I have found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use viewmodel to start blinking. To do what you want, you need to:

- Add new [DataTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) to your ImageStyleUpd style
- Bind it to your isBlinking property with "True" value
- In the trigger you can animate your image however you want (for example, change Opacity of the image)

**Example**

```
<Style x:Key="ImageStyleUpd" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBlinking}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="blinking">
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" AutoReverse="True"
                                         To="0.5" Duration="0:0:0.5">
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="blinking"/>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Hope, it helps.

Comment: I set you as solution, because I have done the same thing following this post: https://programmingistheway.wordpress.com/2015/06/24/mvvm-and-wpf-blink-an-image-from-view-model/

Answer (score 0):

Blinking is typically an animation in the view, which can be started/stopped by `IsBlinking` property in viewmodel. You can achieve blinking effect by varying `DropShadowEffect` (smooth blinking) or by a simple switching of two brushes:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBlinking}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="blinking">
            <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="item"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="Red" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="White" KeyTime="0:0:0.3"/>
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="blinking"/>
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

`item` - is some visual which `Background` (or `Foreground`/`Fill`, etc.) you want to animate.

```
<!-- to example path, use Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" -->
<Path x:Name="item" Fill="SomeDefaultNonBlinkingBrush" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to do this kind of stuff in a behavior, it is reusable and you can set this property on any `UIElement`.

```
public static class FlickrBehavior
{
    #region IsFlickering

    public static bool GetIsFlickering(UIElement element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(IsFlickeringProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsFlickering(UIElement element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsFlickeringProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFlickeringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsFlickering", typeof(bool), typeof(FlickrBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsFlickeringChanged));

    static void OnIsFlickeringChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            StartAnimation(d as UIElement);
        else
            StopAnimation(d as UIElement);
    }

    private static void StartAnimation(UIElement element)
    {
        DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
        da.From = 1;
        da.To = 0;
        da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        da.AutoReverse = true;
        da.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        element.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, da);
    }

    private static void StopAnimation(UIElement element)
    {
        element.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, null);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Novitchi's answer, I would also like to create a behaviour with an attached property. But I will attach the behaviour to the `mouse click`:

So you can create your behaviour as below:

```
public static class BlinkingBehaviour
{
    public static bool GetIsBlinkingWhenClick(UIElement element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(IsBlinkingWhenClickProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsBlinkingWhenClick(UIElement element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsBlinkingWhenClickProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBlinkingWhenClickProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
           "IsBlinkingWhenClick", 
           typeof(bool), 
           typeof(BlinkingBehaviour), 
           new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsBlinkingWhenClickChanged));

    static void OnIsBlinkingWhenClickChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            (d as UIElement).PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= BlinkingWhenClickBehavior_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
            (d as UIElement).PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += BlinkingWhenClickBehavior_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
        }
        else
        {
            (d as UIElement).PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= BlinkingWhenClickBehavior_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
        }
    }

    static void BlinkingWhenClickBehavior_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleAnimation blink = new DoubleAnimation() { 
                        To = 1, 
                        From = 0, 
                        Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200) };
        (sender as UIElement).BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, blink);
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML, you can attach it to your `image`:

```
<Window x:Class="YourNameSpace.YourWindowClass"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace"    
    <Button ...>
        <Image local:BlinkingBehaviour.IsBlinkingWhenClick="True"  .../>
    </Button>
</Window>
```

Comment: Why would you want to limit this behavior only for mouse down event ? How would you stop the blinking when the loading operation is finished ?

Comment: I thought that was what OP wants. Don't understand your second question though, I set the animation to run only once after click. Anyway, OP found the answer he like, we can move on..